# SQL Server Query takes 100% CPU usage what is wrong with my query?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have my queries they are using 100% CPU. I tried to fix them but as i am not database expert its really getting worse.

At first my script executes this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT
       [e].[event_id], 
       [e].[event_name],
       [e].[event_datetime],
       [v].[name] [venue_name],
       [v].[city],
       [s].[state_name],
       [v].[venue_id],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [event_datetime]) AS RowNum
    FROM 
       [indux].[dbo].[event] [e]
    JOIN 
       [indux].[dbo].[venue] [v] ON [e].[venue_id] = [v].[venue_id]
    JOIN 
       [indux].[dbo].[system_state] [s] ON [v].[state_id] = [s].[state_id]
    WHERE 
       [e].[event_id] IN (SELECT DISTINCT event_id 
                          FROM [indux].[dbo].ticket_group 
                          WHERE ticket_group_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT ticket_group_id 
                                                    FROM [indux].[dbo].[ticket] [t] 
                                                    WHERE [t].[actual_sold_price] = -1)
                         )
       AND [e].[event_datetime] >= '2014/08/09'
       AND [e].[event_datetime] <= '2014/12/09'
) AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE 
   MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 250
```

and at in the same time i execute the following query than i combine the results of both to display in my page using PHP

```
SELECT
   COUNT([e].[event_id])
FROM 
   [indux].[dbo].[event] [e]
WHERE 
   [e].[event_id] IN (SELECT DISTINCT event_id 
                      FROM [indux].[dbo].ticket_group 
                      WHERE ticket_group_id IN
                                    (SELECT DISTINCT ticket_group_id 
                                     FROM [indux].[dbo].[ticket] [t] 
                                     WHERE [t].[actual_sold_price] = -1)
                     )
   AND [e].[event_datetime] >= '$today'
   AND [e].[event_datetime] <= '$to'
```

Anyone have any idea if i can fix these queries ? I think the count in second query is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join ticket group and ticket on ticket group ID and join that to the main query on event id.

A nested query runs once for every row of the query whose where clause it is nested in.

nesting twice is like running a loop in a loop and the whole thing has to run once and get compared to the value a value every time the query returns a row. Its apparent from your selects that you can join on those values.

```
SELECT  *Whatever* 
FROM [indux].[dbo].[event] [e]
           JOIN [indux].[dbo].[venue] [v]
        ON [e].[venue_id] = [v].[venue_id]
      JOIN [indux].[dbo].[system_state] [s]
      ON [v].[state_id] = [s].[state_id]
JOIN indux.dbo.ticket_group tg on tg.event_id=r.event_id
JOIN  indux.dbo.ticket t on t.ticket_group_id=tg.ticket_group_id
WHERE t.actual_sold_price=-1

SELECT COUNT(e.event_id)
FROM dbo.event e
JOIN indux.dbo.ticket_group tg on tg.event_id=e.event_id
JOIN  indux.dbo.ticket t on t.ticket_group_id=tg.ticket_group_id
WHERE e.event_datetime >= '$today' 
AND e.event_datetime <= '$to'
```

EDIT for distinctness

```
SELECT  *Whatever* 
FROM [indux].[dbo].[event] [e]
           JOIN [indux].[dbo].[venue] [v]
        ON [e].[venue_id] = [v].[venue_id]
      JOIN [indux].[dbo].[system_state] [s]
      ON [v].[state_id] = [s].[state_id]
JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT tg.event_id 
      FROM indux.dbo.ticket_group tg 
      JOIN indux.dbo.ticket t on t.ticket_group_id=tg.ticket_group_id
      WHERE actual_sold_price = -1) de
on de.Event_id=e.event_id
```

using a temp table ie

```
CREATE TABLE #EventID (id int) 
INSERT INTO #EventID SELECT tg.event_id etc...
```

will allow you to reuse the table rather than re-query for the count statement.

Comment: I will try this and than I will let you know.. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: whats important is the underlying concept you should avoid nesting queries whenever possible as it is quite possibly the slowest way to get something. Even creating a temp table and joining to it would be far preferable.

Comment: its really working but how i can get event_id distinct ?

Comment: I was nesting to get distinct event ID